# The collection of cylinder sets is a semiring

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $ \{(\Omega_i, \mathcal {F}_i, P_i): i \in I\} $ is a non-empty finite or countable collection of probability spaces, and let be $ \Omega: = \prod_{i\in I}\Omega_i$ the product set. A set $A$ is called a cylinder set if $ A = \prod_ {i = 1} ^ {n} A_i $ with $ A_i \in \mathcal {F} _i $. Indicate the collection of all cylinder sets with $ \mathcal {C} $. I have to show that $ \mathcal {C} $ is a semiring.
So that
(1) $ \emptyset \in \mathcal {C} $;
(2) $ A, B \in \mathcal {C} \Rightarrow A \cap B \in \mathcal {C} $;
(3) $ A, B \in \mathcal {C} \Rightarrow exist \; C_1, ..., C_n \in \mathcal {C} $ pairwise disjoint, such that $ A \setminus B = \bigcup_ {i = 1} ^ n C_i $.
I did the first two properties but I can't prove the third property. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Let us do the case where the cylinder are products of two sets. Let $A=A_1\times A_2$ and $B=B_1\times B_2$. Then 
$$
A\setminus B= \left(\left(A_1\setminus B_1\right)\times A_2\right)\cup\left( A_1\times \left(A_2\setminus B_2\right)\right).
$$
This union is in general not disjoint since the intersection of the two sets is $ C_1=\left(A_1\setminus B_1\right)\times \left( A_2\setminus B_2\right)$. 
But we can decompose 
$$
A\setminus B=C_1\cup  \underbrace{\left(\left(A_1\setminus B_1\right)\times \left(A_2\cap B_2\right)\right)}_{=:C_2}\cup  \underbrace{\left(\left(A_1\cap B_1\right)\times \left(A_2\setminus B_2\right)\right)}_{=:C_3}.
$$